# What does mod 0 mean in the context of ergodic theory?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I have come across the following definition:

A measure-preserving transformation (or flow) $T$ is ergodic if any essentially $T$-invariant measurable set has either measure 0 or full measure. Equivalently, $T$ is ergodic if any essentially $T$-invariant measurable function is constant $\mod 0$.

What does $\mod 0$ mean in this context. Does it mean except a set of measure $0$? i.e. the function is constant a.e. ?

Comment: I have never seen that notation used for "almost everywhere," but yes your guess is [correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Formal_definition).

Comment: Just to note that the notation$\bmod 0$ is standard in ergodic theory (you already know the meaning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enciclopedia of mathematics says the following:

"A is called a null (or negligible) set if $\mu_∗(A)=0$; in this case the complement $X\setminus A$ is called a set of full measure (or conegligible), and one says that $x\notin A$ for almost all $x$ (in other words, almost everywhere). Two sets $A,B\subset X$ are almost equal (or equal mod $0$) if $(x\in A) \Leftrightarrow (x\in B)$ for almost all $x$ (in other words, $A\setminus B$ and $B∖A$ are negligible). Two functions $f,g:X \longrightarrow Y$ are almost equal (or equal mod 0, or equivalent) if they are equal almost everywhere. "

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Measure_space